# Accessing a class member from within an asynchronous closure in Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, ecmascript-6

My use case is the `geocoder.geocode` api from the google map library. I'm using it to convert a given user address to a latitude/longitude coordinate for use with another google map api.

This api executes the callback when it is finished searching the input address. From within the callback, I am trying to access a member of my class by using the `this` keyword.

I understand `this`, from within a closure refers to a different context than the class the closure sits in - so at the top of the method I've created variable and cached off the `this` instance, by doing `var self = this`.

This works, but is it the accepted approach? I am using ES6 if that matters.

Comment: You can try arrow function for more elegant code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`var self = this;` was the preferred solution in ES5 and before. I followed the style where no matter what, the first line would always be `var self = this;`. It prevented silly mistakes.

In ES6, we have [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). These are anonymous functions that lexically bind the `this` value. It means that it does not have its own `this`, that regular Javascript functions have. With ES6, you can just do this:

```
var myFunction = function(){ 
    this.someValue = 1;
    someFunction((callbackResult) => { // ARROW FUNCTION
        this.someValue = 2;
    });
};
```

instead of this:

```
var myFunction = function(){ 
    var self = this;

    self.someValue = 1;
    someFunction(function(callbackResult){
        self.someValue = 2;
    });
};
```

Comment: Or `someFunction(callbackResult => this.someValue = 2)`.